# Order multiple app windows in gnome 3.36.9

Tags: 20.04, gnome, window, dock

[image: Gnome 3.36 Windows]

Wanted to order windows. So that I can make other windows as primary.

Comment: What is, according to you, "making a window as primary"? If you mean that you want to change the order of these preview windows in the dock, then, no, you cannot. They appear in the order the apps were launched (if not in MRU order as in older versions - cannot test currently).

Comment: Oh. Why is that so? Is it possible to do it in another DE?

Comment: Probably no developers stepped in yet to implement that feature. Other DE's? Feel free to install and try how they work for you.